# Can't Install Magento SUPEE-3762 Patch

Tags: patches

Magento has a pretty serious bug via soap, and they have a patch for it.

When I run the patch via SSH, I get an error

Here is the patch I'm referring to:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes#ce19-patches-soap

When I run the patch

SH patch-file.sh

I get the following error:

patch: **** malformed patch at line 258:

Line 258 is this:

```
+<?php
```

Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Patching process is pretty simple. If you can't get the patch to work, open the file and at some point near the line you got your error you will see a simple diff prefixed with + and -.

If you want you can just copy the content of the files manually inside the correspondent class (respect the - as a deletion and the + as an insertion in the file you will find on the top of the diff) and that is it, patch applied.